# Где ошибка в функции? Скопировать вложенные объекты

Tags: javascript

Знаю что похожие вопросы уже были, но не могу найти ошибку в своей функции. Нужно скопировать объект вместе с вложенными объектами.

Через цикл:

```js
function copy(dst) {
 for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  var arg = arguments[i];
  for (var key in arg) {
   dst[key] = arg[key];

   if (arg[key] instanceof Object) {
    for (var obj in arg[key]) {
     dst[key][obj] = arg[key][obj];
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return dst;
}

var user = {
 x: {
  y: 5
 }
};

var userClone = copy({}, user);

userClone.x.y = 6;

console.log(user.x.y);
```

Через рекурсию:

```js
function copy(dst) {
 for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  var arg = arguments[i];
  for (var key in arg) {
   dst[key] = arg[key];

   if (arg[key] instanceof Object) {
    copy(dst[key], arg[key]);
   }
  }
 }
 return dst;
}

var user = {
 x: {
  y: 5
 }
};

var userClone = copy({}, user);

userClone.x.y = 6;

console.log(user.x.y);
```

Comment: в рекурсии параметр dst куда-то потерялся

Comment: да, но все равно с ним тоже не работает

Comment: ошибка в строках `dst[key] = arg[key];`, вот тут ты же присвоил ссылку, если это была она, и лишь потом начинаешь проверять, а не ссылочный ли объект был

Comment: по сути эта строка должна выглядеть так: `dst[key] = copy({},  arg[key]);` если `arg[key]` сложный объект :)

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает)